# How to turn on (or prevent turning off) PCI devices?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, acpi, optimus

I'm working on getting VFIO to work on my Optimus laptop (MSI GS75 running Ubuntu with an RTX2060). The only problem that's left to solve is that 3 PCI devices that I need to pass through (apart from the VGA Controller itself) are missing from `lspci` when the Nvidia driver is not running. So if I boot with `prime-select nvidia` all 4 Nvidia devices show up (VGA, Audio, USB & Serial controllers), but when I boot with `prime-select intel` (which is necessary for VFIO), only the VGA Controller shows up in `lspci`.

So there's 2 possibilities as to what's happening as far as I can tell:

1. The Nvidia driver turns **off** the remaining 3 devices during boot when the `intel` profile is selected
2. The Nvidia driver turns **on** the remaining 3 devices during boot when the `nvidia` profile is selected (my guess, but it could be either)

I'm fairly comfortable around Linux but this is a completely new part of Linux for me. If my research is correct it's probably gonna be some ACPI calls, but my knowledge doesn't reach far enough to find out which ACPI calls those should be. I'd appreciate any pointers as to what's indeed happening and how I can get all 4 PCI devices to show up with the `intel` profile selected. Thank you!